# Find the conectives of a composed proposition given a a true table

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, propositional-calculus

How can I construct a proposition P  with the values given in the table using p,q, and r?

\begin{array}{|c3:c|}\hline
p & q & r & P \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1  & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline\end{array}

My fist idea wasto fill each row and given those values , keep  filling the values of the following rows but I always got some contradiction, I have no idea how to solve this :/ Thanks if anyone can help me with another idea to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Use [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

```
     pq
     00 01 11 10
r 0 | 1  1  0  1
  1 | 0  1  1  0
```

The proposition is then given by covering the 1's with rectangles. We see that if *r* is false, *P* is true if *p* NAND *q* is true; this yields a term $\neg r\wedge\neg(p \wedge q)$, or (by de Morgan's laws) $\neg(r \vee(p\wedge q))$. If *r* is true then *q* must be true; this yields a term $r\wedge q$. Hence the final expression for *P* is the OR of these terms:
$$\neg(r \vee(p\wedge q))\vee(r\wedge q)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this mechanically line by line. For the first line consider formula $\neg p\wedge \neg q \wedge\neg r$ call it $P_1$. Obivously $P_1$ is true exactly when you use the evaluation $0,0,0$. Similarly you construct a formula $P_i$ for every line with value $1$. The resulting formula is then their disjunction $\bigvee P_i$. This is actually a way how to transform a formula into disjunctive normal form.