# How can I derive boolean expressions from this truth table?

Tags: logic

My task is this:

Find two formulas for $F$ and $G$ using $P, Q$ and $R$ given the truth table:
$$\begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
P & Q & R & F & G \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}$$

My work so far:

After alot of thought I've come up with one solution for $F$, namely $F = \neg P \lor (Q\land R)$. This however took me far to much time and I'm wondering if someone could explain their reasoning or algorithm when solving for $G$. I have more of these tasks so I would be more than glad if someone could point me in directions to where I might find more info on solving these tables in an *efficient* way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893586/find-the-conectives-of-a-composed-proposition-given-a-a-true-table

Comment: $G = \lnot R \text{ xor } (P \land \lnot Q)$

Comment: @GurIsmael Thanks alot for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards $G$, we note that the rows corresponding to $1$s are:

$(P\land Q\land \neg R)$, $(P\land \neg Q\land R)$, $(\neg P\land Q\land \neg R)$, $(\neg P\land \neg Q\land\neg R)$.

So a formula for $G$ is
$$(P\land Q\land \neg R)\lor (P\land \neg Q\land R)\lor (\neg P\land Q\land \neg R)\lor(\neg P\land \neg Q\land\neg R).$$
In this way you can find easily a formula for your logic function.

If you want a simpler formula, you have to use the properties of the logic operations $\land$, $\lor$, and $\neg$. An efficient way to do it is with the so-called [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

In our case,  $G$ can be simplified to 
$\displaystyle P\land[(Q\land \neg R)\lor (\neg Q\land R)]\lor (\neg P\land \neg R)$.

Comment: Thanks alot for pointing me to Karnaugh maps, and providing a good solution!

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy but tedious solution, namely any logical formula can be presented in [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form):

$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = \bigvee_{(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n) \in \{0,1\}^n} \left(\bigwedge_{i:b_i = 1}x_i\right)\land\left(\bigwedge_{i:b_i = 0}\neg x_i\right)\land f(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n).$$

In your case that would be:

\begin{align}
F(P,Q,R) 
 &=     &&P&\land& &&Q &\land& &&R &\quad\land& &\quad1 \\
 &\hspace{1pt}\lor\hspace{1pt}  &&P&\land& &&Q &\land& &\neg &R &\quad\land& &\quad0 \\
 &\hspace{1pt}\lor\hspace{1pt}  &&P&\land& &\neg &Q &\land& &&R &\quad\land& &\quad0 \\
 &\hspace{1pt}\lor\hspace{1pt}  &&P&\land& &\neg &Q &\land& &\neg &R &\quad\land& &\quad0 \\
 &\hspace{1pt}\lor\hspace{1pt}  &\neg&P&\land& &&Q &\land& &&R &\quad\land& &\quad1 \\ 
 &\hspace{1pt}\lor\hspace{1pt}  &\neg&P&\land& &&Q &\land& &\neg &R &\quad\land& &\quad1 \\
 &\hspace{1pt}\lor\hspace{1pt}  &\neg&P&\land& &\neg &Q &\land& &&R &\quad\land& &\quad1 \\
 &\hspace{1pt}\lor\hspace{1pt}  &\neg&P&\land& &\neg &Q &\land& &\neg &R &\quad\land& &\quad1 \quad=\quad P\land Q\land R \lor \neg P.
\end{align}
The last formula is just a simplification using $x \land 0 = 0$ and $x \land q \lor x \land \neg q = x$.

Note that if $\land$ would be multiplication, $\lor$ addition, and $\neg$ negation, then we would get that $F$ is a *polynomial* in $P,Q,R$, i.e. $F(P,Q,R) = P\cdot Q \cdot R + (-P)$. This is not a coincidence.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Nice way of representing it all, I have to study this one in detail when I pick up where I left this morning. And thanks alot for pointing me to the site on disjunctive normal form!

Answer (score 1):

There are algorithmic ways of doing this, but in this case it just takes a bit of examination.

For $F$, you can see that the bottom half of the table is all $0$ independent of what $Q$ and $R$ are, so $\neg P$ will be part of the expression since it's the opposite of $P$ in that half. In the top half, you should recognize this as an $\wedge$ operation on $Q$ and $R$. Put the pieces together with a $\vee$ and you have your formula.

For $G$, try to see what you recognize from two variables. For example, the bottom half of the table is $\neg R$ and the top half is an exclusive or (denoted XOR, $\oplus$, or $\veebar$ ) on $Q$ and $R$, which can be written in terms of the basic operators as $(Q \vee R) \wedge \neg(Q \wedge R)$. So putting them together, you get

$$[P \wedge (Q \oplus R)] \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg R)$$

which expands to

$$P \wedge [(Q \vee R) \wedge \neg(Q \wedge R)] \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg R)$$